# How to implement DataScannerViewController to React Native

Tags: ios, swift, react-native, visionkit

I am trying to implement DataScannerViewController to react native iOS app. But I am keep getting below error.

This is initializing DataScannerViewController with DataScannerVC

```
import UIKit
import VisionKit
final class DataScannerVC: UIViewController {

    private let dataScannerViewController = DataScannerViewController(recognizedDataTypes: [.text()],
                                                                      qualityLevel: .balanced,
                                                                      recognizesMultipleItems: false,
                                                                      isHighFrameRateTrackingEnabled: true,
                                                                      isPinchToZoomEnabled: true,
                                                                      isGuidanceEnabled: true,
                                                                      isHighlightingEnabled: true)
    
    private var scannerAvailable: Bool { DataScannerViewController.isSupported && DataScannerViewController.isAvailable }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        dataScannerViewController.delegate = self
        
        if scannerAvailable {
            present(dataScannerViewController, animated: true)
            try? dataScannerViewController.startScanning()
        }
    }
}
```

And below is trying to wrap it by UIView. In below I am trying to add DataScannerVC to UIView's parent UIViewController, And also add it's view to parent's view.

```
import UIKit
import VisionKit
class DataScannerView: UIView {
  weak var dataScannerVC: DataScannerVC?//1
  
  @objc var stringULValue: String = "" {
    didSet {
      setNeedsLayout()
    }
  }
  override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
  }
  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) { fatalError("nope") }
  
  override func layoutSubviews() {//2
    super.layoutSubviews()
    if dataScannerVC == nil {
      embed()
    } else {
      dataScannerVC?.view.frame = bounds
    }
  }
  private func embed() {//3
    guard
      let parentVC = parentViewController else {//4
      return
    }
    let vc = parentVC.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "dataScannerVC") as! DataScannerVC
    parentVC.addChild(vc)
    addSubview(vc.view)
    vc.view.frame = bounds
    vc.didMove(toParent: parentVC)
    self.dataScannerVC = vc
  }
}
extension UIView {
    var parentViewController: UIViewController? {
        var parentResponder: UIResponder? = self
        while parentResponder != nil {
            parentResponder = parentResponder!.next
            if let viewController = parentResponder as? UIViewController {
                return viewController
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

But error is, in this line storyboard is null. I think my main problem here is to adding UIViewController to another UIViewController is not right. Do you have any idea to how to implement DataScannerViewController to react native ios app.

```
let vc = parentVC.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "dataScannerVC") as! DataScannerVC
```